# Bind dataSource on Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, repeater

i have an asp repeater control , i bind data source from page load , if there is data , everything works well , but when i have no data to display i want to access footer template to show label : "No available data "

i try with this code :

```
Label lblTotal = (Label)repeaterAccessFooterControl.Controls[repeaterAccessFooterControl.Controls.Count - 1].FindControl("lblTotal");
```

but repeaterAccessFooterControl.Controls.Count always = 0 ..

how can i access footer control from page load,
i think that, in page load, repeater doesn't properly rendered yet .. so that it equals 0

how can i achieve that ??

Comment: It is too early to find a control inside repeater. Check [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.ASPX#data_binding_events_for_databound_controls) to learn how it works.

Comment: Check Out This http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=271

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you have no data to show, that you bind an empty collection to your repeater and not `null` value. Then you can your control with `FindControlRecursive`, like this:

```
var lblTotal = FindControlRecursive(<<your_repater_control>>, "lblTotal") as Label;
```

and here is the definition of `FindControlRecursive`

```
public Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
        {
            return root.ID == id ? root : (from Control c in root.Controls select FindControlRecursive(c, id)).FirstOrDefault(t => t != null);
        }
```

Regards,
Uros

Comment: i need to do that from page load , not fromn ItemDataBound

Comment: i revised my answer, you should put this code after you call DataBind.

Answer (score 0):

Why not switch to a ListView, then you can use the [EmptyDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.emptydatatemplate.aspx)?